# Do physicists understand why time slows down the faster the velocity of an object?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, time-dilation, observers

Like do they understand the mechanism behind it? Is there a mechanism behind it? (for a lack of a better word) Or is it just thought to be a law without any further explanation?

Comment: Yes! And you can understand it too, if you study special relativity. ;) OTOH, if you're *really* asking why does flat spacetime have Minkowski geometry, that may be a little harder to answer...

Comment: Saying "time slows down the faster the velocity of an object" is a pretty imprecise statement in the context of relativity.

Comment: Einstein gave a correct (if not maximally clear) explanation right from the beginning in terms of his axioms. Everything that has happening in special relativity since then is (on the theory side) a clarification or re-formulation of that same stuff; or (on the experimental side) a validation of the predictions that arise from those frameworks. So, unless you are asking about the brute fact of Minkowski space-time the question presumes and lack that simply hasn't been there.

Comment: There is no mechanism behind it. It is not a trick, it is the structure of spacetime. It just happens that our everyday intuitions about space and time are dead wrong at a fundamental level.

Comment: Time doesnt really slow down, but velocity of the elements of the object does.
But since all time measurement is done by velocities, then everything seems to be slower, and you perceive time slow down. But time is still one

Comment: Do we understand why a tree that's directly ahead of you can become directly to your left when you turn around?

Answer (score 16):

Some things you might like to know in relation to this are as follows:

The starting point for all of special relativity is the assumption that the speed of light seems to be the same for everybody, regardless of what speed they are moving relative to each other. From that assumption, with just some basic maths- nothing more difficult than Pythagoras' theorem- you can figure out all of the equations of relativity. So the short answer to your question is that time dilation- which is just one of the effects predicted by the theory- is a result of the constancy of the speed of light.

Quite why light has a constant speed is still an open question. Perhaps we're in the same position as the Greeks, and one day people will find an underlying reason for it.

Time dilation is an entirely reciprocal effect. When we think time is slowing down for someone moving quickly relative to us, they think that our time is slowing down and theirs is running normally. This is a bit like perspective. If I stand far away from you I appear smaller to you, but from my perspective I'm the same size and it is you who has appeared to have shrunk.

Comment: The speed of light is the same for everyone and you also need that there is no preferred inertial frame of reference.

Comment: Conservation of momentum follows from there being no preferred frame of reference - Therefore a way to transform between reference frames must exist, be linear (so that the choice of a reference point doesn't matter) and be closed under composition (transforming from A to B and then from B to C is the same as transforming from A to C). This is pretty limiting and I suspect the only options remaining are the Lorentz transform and the Galilean transform, the latter of which is just a limiting case of the former when the speed of light diverges to infinity.

Comment: @AaronStevens: That just pushes the can further down the road; _why_ need there be no preferred inertial frame of reference?

Comment: @Sean I'm not kicking any cans here. That is literally one of the postulates of special relativity. This answer only mentions the other postulate about the speed of light, so I brought up how you need this postulate as well.

Comment: I'd use the word "observation" instead of "assumption" because by this point we've conducted more than enough experiments to confirm that it is more than mere assumption

Comment: +1 for the comparison with perspective. I had never thought about it that way, but it makes so much sense!

Comment: @slebetman Not only this, but the observation of the constancy of the speed of light came, as far as I know, before the assumption as part of relativity theory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment

Comment: "_why light has a constant speed is still an open question._" 
> 

Although you can write the wave equations from [electromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation) with the speed of light given by the vacuum properties, and if you consider those constants are the same for everyone (it's a "classical" vacuum...) then you'd be able to (weakly) its constancy for any inertial observer. (Or at least I _like_ to think about it in that way ...)

Answer (score 6):

The slowing down of time in special relativity (and the corresponding Lorenz contraction of lengths) is a consequence of the empirical fact that the speed of light in a vacuum is the same for all inertial observers. Why is the speed of light in a vacuum the same for all inertial observers ? Well, that's just how our universe works. It doesn't have to be like that, but that's just how it is.

Comment: But do Physicists acknowledge there is a deeper reason for it? This may not be clear so I will elaborate. The Greeks use to think that when you threw a rock it slowed down simply because that was an intrinsic property. They may have said it just how our unverse works, it didn't have to be like that. But they missed out on the fact the there was order to what was happening. Air was slowing it down to a stop. Do physicists think this is the case with time slowing down for masses in motion?

Comment: @ShannonT Modern physics aims to connect facts together with a common explanation (a.k.a. a "theory"). A more powerful theory explains a wider set of facts, which is a good thing. The two most powerful theories in modern physics are general relativity and quantum mechanics (and unfortunately they are incompatible with  each other !). But modern physics (unlike Greek physics) does not look for a deeper teleological reason for *why* our most powerful theories are as they are.

Comment: I do not think it is empirical that the speed of light is the same for all inertial observers: rather it is an *assumption*.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero [Michelson-Morley experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment)

Comment: right...  Maybe it's clearer to state that it's a postulate that $c$ is constant, and there is not experimental evidence to disprove the assumption.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Yes - lots of experimental evidence that supports, and no experimental evidence that contradicts. Which is what I mean by "empirical fact".

Comment: The "one-way" speed of light, from a source to a detector, cannot be measured independently of a convention as to how to synchronize the clocks at the source and the detector. What can however be experimentally measured is the "two-way" speed of light  from the source to the detector and back again. Albert Einstein chose a synchronization convention (see Einstein synchronization) that made the one-way speed equal to the two-way speed.  Experiments that attempted to directly probe the one-way speed of light independent of synchronization have been proposed, but none has succeeded in doing so.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero gandalf6 is right. When you have the amount of experimental evidence supporting the constancy of $c$, it becomes an empirical fact. And even if it is "two-ways", the precision of the measurments do confirm the constancy well beyond what would be expected if it were not.

Comment: @Alfred I realize my comment was overly historical and follows the more “axiomatic” modern presentation of the subject.

Comment: Let two clocks A and B attached to a rim of a ring that rotates around a source of light. The ring can be of arbitrarily large diameter. Let we synchronize these clocks by beam of light from the center. Then, measured by these clocks A and B one – way speed of light will be different if measured clockwise and in opposite direction. It is 100% clear. If the ring rotates clockwise and its rim is moving with velocity close to that of light, measured by the clocks A and B clockwise one - way speed of light will tend to c/2 and in the opposite direction will tend to infinitely large value.

Comment: This answer mixes up two things: The mathematical MAP of Special Relativity (which discards all detail, keeping just Minkovsky space) and the TERRITORY of the physical system. The territory of the physical system is "explained" by the fact that the map works exceedingly well. But that's not good enough. You will have pull in the rest of physics into the geometric framework of the MAP too or find other explanations for which the geometric framework of SR happens to match. Think of muon decay. Ask WHY ([SciFi example on WHY](https://www.gregegan.net/PLANCK/Complete/Planck.html)).

Answer (score 5):

The deeper reason for it is that the invariant distance between 2 events in spacetime is:

$$ (\Delta s)^2 = (c\Delta t)^2 - (\Delta x)^2$$

What that means is that any observers can measure the time and distance between 2 events, and they will all get the same $\Delta s$, even though they do not agree on spatial separation (obvious), nor on temporal separation (astounding).

The good news is that, while this is very non-intuitive, it actually makes the laws of physics much "nicer" than what most everyone's intuition says, which is that time is a universal parameter that ticks away uniformly for all things in a flat 3 dimensional space.

Comment: there's a minus sign missing somewhere...

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I'm surprised someone else hasn't edited it in. Maybe just stick a $\pm$ in there?

Answer (score 4):

Time dilation is a logical consequence of two postulates:

- The laws of physics are the same for all inertial observers. This is equivalent to saying that there is no preferred inertial reference frame in our universe. People used to think that there was 1 unique reference frame in which the laws of physics are formulated. They thought you had to do your calculations in this unique reference frame and then transform to the reference frame you are working in.
- The propagation speed of physical interactions is finite and equal to the speed of light. This is the principle of locality: an object is directly influenced only by its immediate surroundings.

Time dilation seems counterintuitive because in our daily lives everything moves much slower than the speed of light. To us the propagation speed of physical interactions seems to be infinite. If we replace the speed of light with this infinite speed, we obtain Galilean relativity where time is absolute.

If we lived in a universe where the speed of light was much much slower, special relativity and time dilation would be very natural to us all and you would be asking how, for incredibly slow processes, time seems to be the same for everybody.

Answer (score 2):

At present we must accept the principles of special relativity as is in order to formulate a theory at all.

I'd like to move to a more general perspective, and then back to special relativity specifically.

About progress in fundamental science:

It seems to me that starting with Isaac Newton fundamental science started rolling, and started picking up momentum (pun intended).

Over the past centuries we have experienced pretty much avalanches and avalanches of progress in fundamental science.

So that is the pattern that we have become accustomed to. For example: why is it that when water freezes it expands a little? All other substances just shrink with decreasing temperature. When fundamental science developed an understanding of how the hydrogen atoms and the oxygen atom form a water molecule, and an understanding of the interactions of water molecules with neighbouring water molecules, there and then it was understood why water expands when it freezes.

We have become accustomed to a pattern of fundamental science finding ever deeper insights.

Relativistic physics was introduced more than a 100 years ago. You kind of expect fundamental science to have moved on to an even deeper level.

My assumption is that that is the background of your question. We can explain so much, can we explain the Minkowski metric too?

For comparison:
Kepler's laws of celestial mechanics. Kepler published his three laws of celestial mechanics over a period from 1609 to 1619. It may wel be that at the time there were scholars who thought of Kepler's laws as laws that must be accepted as is. You might like to try and find a deeper level, but if there actually isn't any deeper level you are wasting your time.

Decades later there were scholars who had made some progress. Scholars such Christopher Wren, Edmund Halley, Robert Hooke were aware that Kepler's third law strongly suggests that gravity is an inverse square law. But to show that an inverse square law of gravity gives rise to ellipse-shaped orbits (as described by Kepler's first law) you need differential calculus, and at the time differential calculus wasn't developed yet. Wren, Halley and Hooke had a good hunch; they had a good clue to follow.

As we know now, Isaac Newton had already moved all of mechanics to a whole new level. Upon publication of the Principia these insights became available for all scholars of the time.

Here is why I have spent so many words on Kepler's laws.
Looking at Kepler's three laws it is not immediately apparent that a deeper level of understanding is possible. But of course there *is* a deeper level.

**Special Relativity**

Is it concievable that at some point in the future a deeper insight is reached, such that the Minkowski metric is explained in terms of that deeper theory?

I think that is concievable; you don't know what you don't know. 
It's definitely wrong for anyone to make a blanket statement along the lines of "There is no mechanism, it is the structure of spacetime." That's like a contemporary of Kepler stating: Kepler's laws are the final laws, those laws are the way the universe is."

Then again, if there is a deeper level, we don't have any hunch how/where to look for it. So in terms of *prospects* of finding a deeper theory, it's not looking good.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The trick behind it is to understand what does it mean to measure time and what does it mean to measure distance and once you measure it, how to communicate it to others. The key thing is to define simultaneity in such a way that makes both mathematical and physical sense, because measurement of f.e. distance means to simultaneously read data at the two points of your measuring tape or whatever you use. So you need some method to determine when the measurement was indeed simultaneous.

And so it happened, that nature gave us one nice process that allows for nice definition of simultaneity which obeys all the physical and mathematical requirements - propagation of light.

How the light propagates, however, must be taken as fact of nature, that has no deeper mechanism. But once you have this, the supposed slowing down of time is just due to how different observers look at what time is.

There is no mechanism however, because there is really no notion of time that is intrinsic to nature. The nature has different structure - that of minkowski spacetime, but does not have structure of space and time. The fact that we get used to the dividing spacetime on space and time is "our problem". Nature is not that way and that leads to all the "difficulties" we get when we try to do it outside of our day-to-day experiences.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment but I would like to point out that even without Einstein's relativity and in an absolute frame of reference all inter-particle communication happens slower and slower as velocity increases, if you consider communication as message exchanges between particles at the speed of light. This would result in outside observers experiencing mass increase in the accelerated object and the object experiencing its own time as slower .

Answer (score -4):

All this space time talk is unnecessary and confusing.  The concept of time slowing down means the frequency of the sound or radio/light wave you are using to communicate appears to increase when 2 objects are coming together and decrease when they are moving apart.  Suppose Nolan Ryan (former Texas Rangers pitcher) is standing a mile away from you and throwing a ball toward you once per second. (He had to eat an extra helping of cheerios to perform that feat). The frequency is once per second.  However, you don't catch the first ball until a second later, so we have a combination of frequency and distance involved here.  If he is standing still, the frequency will be once per second.  But if he is standing up strapped to the back of a pickup truck going sixty miles per hour (a mile a minute) and throws the first ball exactly one mile from you, the ball will be moving 88 feet per second faster than it was when he was standing still.  Also when he throws the second ball one second later, the ball will have to travel 88 feet less that one mile, so the additional speed of the ball and the decreased distance it has to travel means the ball will reach you sooner than one second, and the same with the next ball. This results in an increased frequency of 5280 feet (5280 feet in a mile) divided by 176 (88 feed faster, 88 feet shorter) or 1.034 balls (pulses) per second compared to 1 pulse per second if Mr. Nolan were standing still.  My calculations may not be precise, but that is the principle.  So when a car passes you, the frequency appears higher when it approaches you, then immediately appears lower as it passes.  If you were receiving radio communications between 2 objects approaching each other - whether from sound or radio waves, the sound frequency would appear to increase from both sides; it would also appear to decrease when the objects travel apart.  Virtually everyone has experienced this.  A logical conclusion to this is that if you leave earth in a space ship, the time (radio frequency) would appear to decrease, but when you returned to earth the time (radio frequency) would appear to increase correspondingly so you will not have lost even a microsecond.  So Planet of the Apes is pure scientific fiction.  Not really difficult to understand.  When a physicist says that time slows down or speeds up between two objects moving at different speeds, the physicist is simply replacing a clear explanation with a confusing scientific misnomer.  If I can confuse you, I must be smarter than you.
The e=mc2 formula is also just as simple to explain.  I like to think of Mr. Einstein as a Master of Illusion.

Comment: What you are describing is the Doppler effect, which is distinct from the time dilation described by special relativity. Time dilation occurs regardless of the direction of motion (i.e. the same dilation is observed whether an object is moving away, towards or transverse to you), whereas the frequency shift due to the Doppler effect changes depending on the direction of motion.

Comment: A physical principle needs to be generalised in order for it to be of greater use to the general scientific community. Thus the Doppler effect as you are describing, is really tied to relativity and not the balls being thrown off of pick-up trucks.

Comment: I agree I was describing the doppler effect.  The balls in motion simply provide a somewhat visible explanation. I see no other explanation for the time dilation, and until someone provides that, I stand by what I have written.